# I am trying to create a program that edits text by letting you select from a few things and changes them to one of a few options

Tags: python, text

```
    import os, re
config_file = "jsm_gyro_config.txt"
#fptr = open(config, "w")
#text = "demo text"
#fptr.write(text)
#fptr.close()

file = open(config_file, 'r')
file-read = file.read()

for line in file-read:
    if re.search(userinput, file-read):
        x = re.search(userinput, file-read)
        # iteminputted is what the user wants to replace
        iteminputted = "ref"
        startpostion = x.span[1] + 3
        endpostion = startposition + len(iteminputted)
        # Find out how to write to a specific location in a file that will finish this off
    else:
        print("Item not found")
```

This is what i've tried and here is my thought process as always any help is appreatated and please make it understandable for an idiot :(

Comment: What is the problem? What is your question?

Comment: Welcome to SO. This isn't a discussion forum or tutorial. Please take the [tour] and take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page.  Invest some time with [the Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html) practicing the examples. It will give you an idea of the tools Python offers to help you solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

To begin with, you should not use `-` in your variable declarations as it is actually an operator and will always be treated as such. It will attempt to subtract.

Here is the same code with that fixed and also with the input

```
import os, re
config_file = "jsm_gyro_config.txt"
#fptr = open(config, "w")
#text = "demo text"
#fptr.write(text)
#fptr.close()

file = open(config_file, 'r')
file_read = file.read()
file.close() # You should always close your files.

for line in file_read:
    if re.search(userinput, file_read):
        x = re.search(userinput, file_read)
        # iteminputted is what the user wants to replace
        iteminputted = input("Input what you would like to replace > ")
        startpostion = x.span[1] + 3
        endpostion = startposition + len(iteminputted)
        # Find out how to write to a specific location in a file that will finish this off

    else:
        print("Item not found")
```

However your question is very unclear, I did the best I could.